# How do I delete the ' | ' character when I use sql?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

New to SQL and I have this question. When I print my database onto my terminal, it shows up like this: Ex: Harry | Potter | Gryffindor.

Where those are the 3 columns that correspond to first name, last name, and house. Now, how do I print out those 3 exact words, but without the " | "? Then my result would look like this: Harry Potter Gryffindor. thanks

Comment: What database are you using and what software are you using to query that database? For example, are you using Oracle database and SQL Developer?

Comment: im using SQL developer

Comment: If you are using SQL Developer then you are querying an Oracle database. You should [edit] your question and add those tags.

Comment: share your query that you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could just select the concatenation of these three fields, e.g.

```
SELECT first_name || ', ' || last_name || ', ' || house AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Some version of SQL have a `CONCAT` function which can also be used for string concatenation:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ', ', last_name, ', ', house) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: the first one you gave doesn't work. it gave me an error said : near "||": syntax error

Comment: This is very strange then, because only the first version should be working on Oracle.